# How can I make node_color and node_size from items in a column and plot in networkx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, networkx

I am trying to understand networkx. I am testing the sample code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
 
# Input data files check
from subprocess import check_output
 
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
 
G = nx.Graph()

#df_nodes = df_deduped[['Circuit_Number','IEEE_Description','Duration','Device_County','Picklist_Count','Customers_Served_On_Circuit']].copy()
#df_nodes = df_nodes[df_nodes['Picklist_Count'].between(15, 30)]
#df_nodes = df_nodes.head(100)


data = [{'Circuit': 'html','Description':1, 'Duration':10.2, 'Source':'Westchester', 'Destination':'Davie', 'Picklist':1000, 'Postlist':50000.2}, 
       {'Circuit': 'html', 'Description':2, 'Duration':12.1, 'Source':'Westchester', 'Destination':'Davie', 'Picklist':3000, 'Postlist':40000.1},
       {'Circuit': 'html', 'Description':3, 'Duration':11.3, 'Source':'Westchester', 'Destination':'Davie', 'Picklist':7000, 'Postlist':50000.2}, 
       {'Circuit': 'html', 'Description':3, 'Duration':8.1, 'Source':'West', 'Destination':'San Bernardino', 'Picklist':3000, 'Postlist':40000.0},
       {'Circuit': '.net', 'Description':4, 'Duration':6.2, 'Source':'Queens', 'Destination':'San Bernardino', 'Picklist':5000, 'Postlist':6000.1}, 
       {'Circuit': '.net', 'Description':3, 'Duration':20.1, 'Source':'Queens', 'Destination':'Los Angeles', 'Picklist':5000, 'Postlist':4000.1},
       {'Circuit': '.net', 'Description':2, 'Duration':15.5, 'Source':'Brooklyn', 'Destination':'San Francisco', 'Picklist':5000, 'Postlist':9000.3},
       {'Circuit': '.net', 'Description':4, 'Duration':7.7, 'Source':'Brooklyn', 'Destination':'Davie', 'Picklist':6000, 'Postlist':10000},
       {'Circuit': '.net', 'Description':4, 'Duration':7.7, 'Source':'Los Angeles', 'Destination':'Westchester', 'Picklist':6000, 'Postlist':10000},
       {'Circuit': '.net', 'Description':4, 'Duration':7.7, 'Source':'San Berdarnino', 'Destination':'Westchester', 'Picklist':6000, 'Postlist':10000}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df


node_color = []
for word in df['Circuit']:
    if word not in node_color:
        node_color.append(word)
        
node_size = []
for word in df['Picklist']:
    if word not in node_size:
        node_size.append(word)


# G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, "Description", "Picklist")
 
fig = plt.figure()
nx.draw_networkx(df, "Source", "Destination", node_color=node_color, node_size=node_size, font_color="whitesmoke")
fig.set_facecolor('blue')
plt.show()
```

When I run the code, I get the error described below. What am I doing wrong here?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ipykernel_3332\2173665631.py in <module>
     45 
     46 fig = plt.figure()
---> 47 nx.draw_networkx(df, "Source", "Destination", node_color=node_color, node_size=node_size, font_color="whitesmoke")
     48 fig.set_facecolor('blue')
     49 plt.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py in draw_networkx(G, pos, arrows, with_labels, **kwds)
    301         pos = nx.drawing.spring_layout(G)  # default to spring layout
    302 
--> 303     draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, **node_kwds)
    304     draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, arrows=arrows, **edge_kwds)
    305     if with_labels:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py in draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist, node_size, node_color, node_shape, alpha, cmap, vmin, vmax, ax, linewidths, edgecolors, label, margins)
    423 
    424     try:
--> 425         xy = np.asarray([pos[v] for v in nodelist])
    426     except KeyError as err:
    427         raise nx.NetworkXError(f"Node {err} has no position.") from err

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    423 
    424     try:
--> 425         xy = np.asarray([pos[v] for v in nodelist])
    426     except KeyError as err:
    427         raise nx.NetworkXError(f"Node {err} has no position.") from err

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0):

[`nx.draw_networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html) expects a networkx graph as its first argument, but you've passed a dataframe there. 
And as the error traceback shows, where it have to iterate over the nodes of a graph in `[pos[v] for v in nodelist]` - it obtained a dataframe which when iterated emits column names giving you an obvious error.

Comment: I sort of understand, but not totally. I just changed it to this:

nx.draw_networkx(G, "Source", "Destination", node_color=node_color, node_size=node_size, font_color="whitesmoke")

Getting an error again.

Comment: @ASH, when I change `df` to `G` in that call I get this image https://ibb.co/80MzjFt without errors